# Amazon S3 upload speeds and maxConnections config setting

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

I was doing some upload speed tests for various configurations for Amazon S3 and I noticed something strange.

If I have my `maxConnections` set to 4, Amazon uploads slowly (which is what I was expecting).  However, if I have it set to 2, it runs at the same speed as it does when it's set to 8-16.

```
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="2" />
  </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

Why does "2" not seem to have any effect when using Amazon S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I debugged the upload code, I found that if the config file has "maxConnections" set to 2, the AmazonS3Config.ConnectionLimit is set to 50.  However, if I set it directly to 2, it will stay there.

```
s3ClientCfg.ConnectionLimit = ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit;
```

If I set it to 1, 3, 4 or any other value via the .config file, I don't notice that.  Apparently, they decided that if the value is coming from the config file and it's the default 2, set it to 50 to improve out-of-the-box upload speeds.